# Connecting threaded 3.5mm jack plug to non-threaded socket?

Tags: conversion, audio-recording, connectors

I have a lav mic with a threaded jack at the end. It came with a Sennheiser Transmitter/Receiver pair and has a threaded jack to connect into the Transmitter which has a threaded socket to match.

However, I often don't need the distance the RF gives me and it would be easier just to plug the lav mic directly into my recorder -- usually a Zoom H6, but sometimes even just an iPhone.

Trouble is, neither the H6 nor iPhone have a threaded socket and the construction of the threaded jack on the lav is such that it can't fit all the way into a normal unthreaded socket. In fact it even bounces out since the threading is on a little spring-loaded collar.

I've hunted all through my kit to find some combination of my existing bits and pieces that would let me connect lav to H6, but no joy. But now I'm wondering if maybe what I'm trying to do is in some way *verboten* , and the threaded-osity (it *could* be a word!) is kinda like a key or warning not to do it!

So, is it OK to do what I'm trying to do -- connect lav to H6, or lav to iPhone -- or is it a recipe for frying some wee input or output component? Or if it's a legit thing to do, then what's the normal way to do it? Is there a name for the converter/doofer/widget I should be looking for to allow me to connect my threaded 3.5mm male to connect to an unthreaded 3.5mm female?

Comment: Welcome! What make and model is the microphone? Do you have a link to a spec sheet, manual, or anything else helpful?

Comment: All I know is it came with a Sennheiser G3 kit. So probably the [ME-2](https://en-us.sennheiser.com/mini-lavalier-microphone-clip-on-live-speech-vocals-instrument-miking-me-2) but I can’t be 100% sure. That said, the most important part of my question is really the physical connection — i.e. 3.5mm threaded jack into non-threaded socket. I’d imagine that is pretty standard (although, again, I can’t be sure).

Comment: This? https://m.cdw.com/product/Sennheiser-CL1-microphone-adapter/3694483?cm_cat=GoogleBase&cm_ite=3694483&cm_pla=NA-NA-SEN_MI&cm_ven=acquirgy&ef_id=Wxw0PAAABTHR@hgM:20181002202403:s&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_9bt-cro3QIVGNRkCh1PXA0JEAQYFiABEgJHKPD_BwE&s_kwcid=AL!4223!3!250790903421!!!g!301248646211!

Comment: Thanks. Almost. But that's threaded plug to unthreaded plug. I need threaded *socket* to unthreaded plug. But your example prompted me to search more, and at one point I stopped looking for "threaded" and started looking for "locking", which is at least as common a descriptor. I think [this is what I'm after](https://www.amazon.com/Female-Locking-Stereo-Adapter-007594/dp/B077BT9Y4Y).